# "required" keyword in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I got the below schema from http://json-schema.org/examples.html, i want to know if the required keyword can only come at the top level. or it can also come within the properties if there is a property of type object.I could not find any thing related to this in the specification https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.4.3.

```
{
    "title": "Example Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "description": "Age in years",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 0
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

So the below example is a valid schema

```
{  
   "title":"Example Schema",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{  
      "firstName":{  
         "type":"string"
      },
      "lastName":{  
         "type":"string"
      },
      "age":{  
         "type":"object",
         "properties":{  
            "minAge":{  
               "type":"number"
            },
            "maxAge":{  
               "type":"number"
            },
            "required":[  
               "minAge",
               "maxAge"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "required":[  
      "firstName",
      "lastName"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Your nested `required` is in the wrong place.  It needs to be a peer of `properties`, not a child.  You got it right in the top level, so I'm sure this was just typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 4.4 Keywords with the possibility to validate container instances (arrays
>      or objects) only validate the instances themselves and not their
>      children (array items or object properties).

So I see that yes, you can have those on any level but the validation should be only consider on the same level as required

Comment: so my latest edit is a valid schema, it has requires at multiple level.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  Validation does work recursively.  In fact, JSON Schema validation would be rather useless if this quote meant what you think it does.  Assume you are validating an array whose items must match a given schema.  If those items don't validate, validation will not fail on the `items` keyword, it will fail on the overall array validation.  What the quote means is that the keyword is only responsible for determining which schema to validate against.  It is not responsible for validating against the schema.  That happens in another step.

Comment: @Jason , could you elaborate more , i could not understand the validation on array items , if you could share a simple schema with array validation it would be more clear.

Comment: @user2478236, it is difficult to elaborate more in a comment.  I suggest you use [jsonschemalint](http://jsonschemalint.com/draft4/#) to create some schemas and see how they validate against example data.

Comment: @Jason " In fact, JSON Schema validation would be rather useless if this quote meant what you think it does. " - it seems like it simply means that validation should be performed on _the same level_. This can lead to the conclusion that every level should have its own "required" rules - which answers the questions and looks like it is, indeed, correct.

Comment: @M4ks, I read your answer to say that a validator should only validate the top level of the schema and ignore any children.  That is why I said JSON Schema wouldn't be very useful if this were true.  I understand now what you were really trying to say.  Sorry I called your answer wrong.  It just needed a little more elaboration.  However, I still assert that your interpretation of the passage you quoted is incorrect.  The explanation in my first comment is what it is intended to mean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `required` is a valid keyword in any schema. There are no restrictions for nested schemas.

To use your example, the following is a valid schema and will validate the way you want it to.

```
{  
    "title": "Example Schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {  
        "firstName": {  
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {  
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {  
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {  
                "minAge": {  
                    "type": "number"
                },
                "maxAge": {  
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "required": [  
                "minAge",
                "maxAge"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [  
        "firstName",
        "lastName"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `required` keyword can be present in any schema.  This is true of all schema keywords.

(There is a special-case for the meta-keyword `$schema`, for which it is *advisable* to only have in the top level)